# How can I create a custom shortcode in Magento2 for products within a category?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to find out how to get a list of products within a category that I can embed into a block - for example {{products category='safe-equipment'}}

I am new to Magento, so please give me the dumbed down version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your block.  In content section, click 'Insert Widget' button.  Choose 'Catalog Products List' for type.  Click last option, 'Condition', and set to 'Product Attribute -> Category'.  Then use the category chooser to select the category.  Your Condition should look something like "Category is {category id}".  The other options are pretty much self explanatory.  When you click 'Create Widget' magento will insert code in your block that looks like this:

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="1" products_per_page="5" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`75`;]]"}}
```